# Return an array of items that satisfies a specific rule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an example class which acts as a rule like below and they will be more rules in the future. In this case it checks if an item is an insurance and if it is then the `satisfied?` method comes in play:

```
class ItemAvailabilityRule
  def applicable?(item:)
    item.name == Item::INSURANCE
  end

  def satisfied?(bookable:, item:)
    applicable?(item) && bookable.duration_in_days < 365
  end
end
```

I have another class which applies the rules to items as below:

```
class ItemsAvailabilityPolicy
  def initialize(rules: [])
    @rules = rules
  end

  def apply(bookable:, items:)
    items.map do |item|
      applicable_rules = rules.select { |rule| rule&.applicable?(item: item) && rule&.applicable?(bookable: bookable, item: item) }
      applicable_rules.detect { |rule| !rule.satisfied?(bookable: bookable, item: item) }
    end
  end
end
```

My apply method is not quite right I think..

What I want to achieve through this apply method is that for an individual item using this:
`applicable_rules = rules.select { |rule| rule.applicable?(item: item) }` will give me all of the rules that apply to that item. 
I then want to check if there is at least one unsatisfied rule
for which I did:
 `applicable_rules.detect { |rule| !rule.satisfied?(bookable: bookable, item: item) }`

I then want to remove items from the array that do not satisfy all of the applicable rules and returns an array with only the ones that satisfied the rule.. How can I achieve that?

Comment: So you want to select items satisfying all applicable rules?

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it:

```
class ItemsAvailabilityPolicy
  def initialize(rules: [])
    @rules = rules
  end

  def apply(bookable:, items:)
    items.select do |item|
      applicable_rules = rules.select { |rule| rule&.applicable?(item: item) && rule&.applicable?(bookable: bookable,
 item: item) }
      non_satisfactory = applicable_rules.detect { |rule| !rule.satisfied?(bookable: bookable, item: item) }
      non_satisfactory.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

The changes are minimal, first change `map` to `select` so you are only selecting items that return `true` from your block.  `Enumerable#select` needs a truthy or falsy return from each item in the block so we use `blank?`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right (as Stefan asked) you want to return all items satisfying all applicable rules ? And you have a "bookable" object that you want to test against all the items in a collection. This assumes that each rule will be applied in the same way (i.e. with the same variables etc)

You dont really need to use any local variables here since `Array#select` is what you need (for the items) and you can use `select` again for the applicable rules and chain that with `Array#all?` to ensure the item (which you are possibly selecting) passes all the (applicable) rules....

Here's the code (easier to understand than the explanation!)

```
class ItemsAvailabilityPolicy
  def initialize(rules: [])
    @rules = rules
  end

  def apply(bookable:, items:)
    items.select do |item|
      @rules.select { |rule| rule.applicable?(item: item) }.all? do |rule|
        rule.satisfied?(bookable: bookable, item: item)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

N.B. I used @rules because you used an instance var and no `attr_reader` or `attr_accessor`

Hope that helps